# I cant view the table i made in the design pane

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

The Design view is not showing the table i created

Comment: probably no data being returned from your dataset

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a table can get moved off screen. If you're not able to see it from scrolling with the horizontal and vertical scroll bars, you can check to see it's LOCATION properties. I've had a couple of times where the LOCATION somehow ended up with negative values and was off the page.

In the Properties window on the right, use the drop-down menu to select the table. In the LOCATION property of the table, set the values to `0,0` if they are negative numbers.

[image]